# How to create custom common component for element plus ui input in nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-component, vuejs3, parent-child, nuxtjs3

I want to create the custom component for element plus inputs in nuxt 3. I have created the component but am confused about how to set the v-modal on child component.  As per the vue 3 `braking changes` https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html I have tried the same syntax but not working. Please check the below code snippet that I have tried in nuxt 3 as per the vue 3 braking changes.

**Parent component**

```html
<template>

<Input :modelValue="inputname" @update:modelValue="inputname=$event"/>

</template>

<script setup>

const inputname = ref("");

<script/>
```

**Child component**

```html
<template>
  <el-form-item prop="name">
    <el-input type="text" v-model="props.modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"/>
  </el-form-item>
</template>
<script setup>
defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "",
  },
});
<script/>
```

I have tried the above mentioned things but it not working. I need help to make it smooth and short syntax code to manage v-modal in child component with reliable and understandable code.

Also want to know if there is any restriction to using the prop name as `modelValue` or if we can use anything we want.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing the event instead of the value.
These changes make in work for me.

Change from

```js
<input type="text" v-model="props.modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"/>
```

to

```js
<input type="text" v-model="props.modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"/>
```

If you're going to use a lot of v-models you can try VueUse's [UseVModel](https://vueuse.org/core/usevmodel/). (If you're looking to forward the v-model this isn't necessary though).
[Installation guide](https://vueuse.org/guide/). Like this:

Parent

```js
<template>
    <Input v-model="inputname" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const inputname  = ref("")
</script>
```

Child

```js
<template>
    <el-form-item prop="name">
        <el-input type="text" v-model="data" />
    </el-form-item>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps<{modelValue: string}>();
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const data = useVModel(props, 'modelValue', emit)

</script>
```

Comment: Are u sure child is a child and parent is a parent? I edited it, but I still not sure why parent has `defineEmits()` and `defineProps()`. Template in parent looks like parent, that why I changed names.

Comment: @Felix Eklöf @Mises
Thank you very much for your answer. I have your code too but still not working. Also, do you know in nuxt 3 which vue 3 version is used? Is `nuxt 3` used vue `v3.2.45`